# Can this inhomogeneous PDE be solved?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following inhomogeneous PDE, which I would like to know if it can be solved:
$$
\Delta F(\vec r) + \alpha G(\vec r)F(\vec r) = -\beta G(\vec r)
$$
In here, Greek letters are constants. Fortunately, the function $G(\vec r)$ is known everywhere in the domain of consideration. For what I know if the second term on the LHS would not exist, it would be Poisson's equation. For that I know the solution.

Actually I have two questions:

1. What is that type of equation called? — Nonlinear, inhomogeneous, second order PDE?
2. Can it be solved?

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards!

Comment: This is a linear elliptic equation, which is of the form $\Delta u + Bu + cu = f$, where $B = \sum_j b^j \partial_j$ is a vector field, and $c$ is a function. These are well studied. Solutions don't always exist, but there is a Fredholm alternative for existence of solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, helps me a lot!